# Invoking method from within a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a following trigger defined in the xaml.How do I programmatically invoke Test_MouseDown from within this Trigger please?

Thanks for your help.

MyWindow.xaml

```
<Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="helpers:MyHelper.IsMouseLeftButtonDown" Value="True">
                        <!--Call some method present in the xaml.cs file-->
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
```

MyWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void Test_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can directly call a event from trigger. prefer bindings and trigger for use case if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use behavior instead of property trigger.

Firstly, add the following two assemblies references to your project:

> System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
>
> Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll

Then add the following namespaces in your xaml file:

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Then add the following xaml code to the target element:

```
<Window ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(helpers:MyHelper.IsMouseLeftButtonDown)}" Value="True">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Test_MouseDown" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
        </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

In the window.xaml.cs, you should provide a method named `Test_MouseDown` like this:

```
    public void Test_MouseDown()
    {
        // your logic here
    }
```